# A Question Regarding the Command optimization.step(closure) in PyTorch

Tags: optimization, pytorch

I, as a PyTorch beginner, have a question regarding the command `optimizer.step(closure)` . According to PyTorch documentation:

*Some optimization algorithms such as Conjugate Gradient and LBFGS need to reevaluate the function multiple times, so you have to pass in a closure that allows them to recompute your model. The closure should clear the gradients, compute the loss, and return it.*

*Example:*

```
    def closure():
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(input)
        loss = loss_fn(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        return loss
    optimizer.step(closure)
```

What I cannot understand is why we need to define closure for some particular optimization algorithms?